# The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE) . visio crashes when accessing it using IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I am new to .net & I am facing an unusual issue with my application. I am developing an application which opens up a visio file with certain shapes from a .net application. I am doing my development work in a Windows7 home premium 64 bit PC. I am using visual studio professional 2012 for development. I have installed Visio premium 2010. My application works fine when running from the visual studio (application runs in with the default IIS express which comes with visual studio). Now I am trying to deploy the application in to actual IIS server in the same development box. I enabled the IIS (version7.5) in my windows7 development box. I deployed the application in IIS without any issue(I followed this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0). But when I try to open the visio file from the application (by clicking a button.) I am getting the following error.

> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The
>   remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[COMException (0x800706be): The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)]
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.DocumentsClass.Add(String FileName) +0
   Export_Visio.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +294
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

I am not sure why this error is happening only when I am running in IIS and not in IIS express which comes with Visual Studio. I checked at the event logs to see if I could get any further information on this. What I got from that is as follows.

> Faulting application name: VISIO.EXE, version: 14.0.6122.5000, time
>   stamp: 0x4fb499bf Faulting module name: VISLIB.dll, version:
>   14.0.6122.5000, time stamp: 0x4fb499f9 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x001303ae Faulting process id: 0x14d0 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01ce3e171e27cc2f Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\VISIO.EXE Faulting
>   module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office14\VISLIB.dll Report Id:
>   5d12428f-aa0a-11e2-b7f3-e840f2736aca

Can someone please help me to find out what is causing this issue?

Note: my other office products installed in this computer are 2003 version(word, excel, power point etc) if that matters. Visio is 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any idea ?? I am still struggling with the same issue.

Comment: I m having similar issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?